# Permissions Query with PHP/APACHE/MAC OSX Lion

Tags: php, ios, apache, configuration

I am new to coding on a mac and I am having a few problems with what I assume are permissions.

I am trying to configure PHP and Apache on a Macbook Pro that runs Lion 10.7.5.

I have activated apache.

I have edited the the httpd.conf file to activate PHP.

When trying to access the PHP homepage `http://localhost/~username/phpinfo.php` I receive the following 403 error:

"You don't have permission to access /~username/phpinfo.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at localhost Port 80"

As mentioned, I presume this is a permissions error, however I have absolutely no experience using terminal. If I am on the right track, can someone please give me a guide on how to lift these restrictions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm keen to get cracking on some actual code.

Thanks,
Bigscreentv

Comment: I'd go with MAMP or look into vagrant if I'm honest.

Comment: Suggestion noted. MAMP is much easier. Thanks.